# Qml property hooks

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

Suppose there is a Qml type called `Test` with `foo` property, it is implemented as follows:
`Test.qml`

```
// Not necessarily QtObject, but derived from QObject
QtObject {
    // Not necessarily var/property, but must behave like property (i.e. be accessible using "<instance>.foo")
    property var foo
}
```

And used in the following way:
`main.qml`

```
import "."

Test {
    id: _test
}

function baz() {
    var x = _test.foo;
    _test.foo = x;
}
```

What I want is to be notified every time `foo` property is accessed by getter or setter. For setter perhaps I can use `fooChanged` signal, but there is no such solution for getter. Also I could implement `Test` type as a `C++` class with `Q_PROPERTY` macro and emit corresponding signals form property getter/setter, but I would really like to leave most of the code on Qml side.

Is there any other way to hook Qml properties access?

Comment: Interesting question. AFAIK there's no direct way to do that. Anyhow you can use `QtObject` to make the variable private and call a custom signal in the setter/getter, much like you proposed to do in C++ but fully implemented in QML. IMO the C++ version feels a little bit more polished. I guess it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after some hours of googling, reading Qml and JS documentation I think I have finally found a solution. It involves some hacks since JS is not fully supported in Qml, but this solution still works. The main idea is to use JS `defineProperty` method in order to add properties to existing objects dynamically. Now my `Test.qml` file looks like this:

```
QtObject {
    // NOTE: .defineProperty does not correctly work for Qml objects, so JS object is used instead
    property var object: { return {}; }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Object.defineProperty(
            object,
            "foo",
            {
                get: function () {
                    // getter handling here
                },
                set: function (value) {
                    // setter handling here
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And in `main.qml` `_test` instance is declared as follows:

```
property alias _test: _testDeclaration.object

Test {
    id: _testDeclaration
}
```

Hope this answer will help other people.

Comment: Note that instead of `property var object: { return {}; }` you can use `property var object: ({})`. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html#property-value-initialization-semantics